# JavaScript function not returning true

Tags: javascript, function, return

I have the following js function and I'm pulling my hair out trying to determine why it won't return 'true'. I've verified the logic block is being hit by adding an alert into the block but it seems to skip the line containing the return statement.

```
function requiresMatchLevel(fields) {
        $.each(fields, function (i, field) {
            if (field.OperationParamName() == "MatchLevel" && field.Include()) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        return false;
    };
```

Comment: `return true;` returns from the `each` method here, not your method.

Comment: Could it be because the return is within the anonymous method? That is, if you replaced the "return true" with an assignment to a function-local variable, then returned that value as the result, perhaps that would overcome the issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`return` acts on a per-function basis. Returning in the function passed to `$.each` will not have your outer function return something.

If you return something in the function passed to `$.each`, jQuery will receive the result. The only value that has effect here is `false`, which makes jQuery break out of the loop.

```
function requiresMatchLevel(fields) {
    var result = false;
    $.each(fields, function (i, field) {
        if (field.OperationParamName() == "MatchLevel" && field.Include()) {
            result = true;
            return false;  // break out of loop - no need to continue
        }
    });
    return result;
};
```

Comment: Hassan's comment was right on the money. pimvdb's refactor worked great!

Comment: @user135498: Great you were able to solve it. As a side note, on newer browsers you can simplify this construct (i.e. returning true if any array item suffices a condition) with just `return fields.some(function() { ... });`.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
function requiresMatchLevel(fields) {
        var isMatch = false;
        $.each(fields, function (i, field) {
            if (field.OperationParamName() == "MatchLevel" && field.Include()) {
                isMatch = true;
            }
        });
        return isMatch;
    };
```

Comment: Your solution should break out of the each loop, currently it will loop through everything if it has a match.

Answer (score 1):

When you are running a jquery function and returns true, true is returned to jquery. Try some of this:

```
function requiresMatchLevel(fields) {
    var toBeReturned=false;
    $.each(fields, function (i, field) {
        if (field.OperationParamName() == "MatchLevel" && field.Include()) {
            toBeReturned=true;
        }
    });
    return toBeReturned;
};
```

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function requiresMatchLevel(fields) {
        var ret = false;
        $.each(fields, function (i, field) {
            if (field.OperationParamName() == "MatchLevel" && field.Include()) {
                ret = true;
                return false; // here you need to return false just like break out a loop.
            }
        });
        return ret;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

use RETURN yourfuncttion();

on the event.